# How did pics go from a phone to the laptop without him knowing it?

Tags: phone

My husband set up someone's laptop and used his phone to assist. Our private pics have ended up on this person's laptop without our knowledge or consent. How could this happen? Surely one must transfer the files or save them?

Comment: What phone? What computer? Your husband must have clicked "yes" at some point, maybe not reading the fine print. For example, a Samsung phone will try to transfer to a Samsung PC almost everything, if you are not careful to read through the automatic prompts.

Answer (score 3):

If your husband used his Microsoft (ex: hotmail.com ; msn.com ; outlook.com) or Apple login to setup this PC that could be why the photos synced. Microsoft OneDrive is the app that automatically syncs files/photos on a Windows PC. Apple iCloud is the app on macbooks/iPhones. To make matters a bit more confusing you can use Microsoft OneDrive on a Google Android smartphone or an Apple iPhone/iPad which is likely how the photos got from the phone to the PC as its a 'cloud backup' system. Takeaway don't setup someone else's equipment with your own email/account as its a bit tricky to unlink that, but it is very much possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is good to know. I also asked him why on earth he would use his fone. My next question would be is what else got saved to this persons laptop from his phone 

Comment: IF he logged in with his Microsoft or Apple account it could sync ANY file in Microsoft OneDrive or Apple iCloud. You need to give us as much info as possible for us to help you the best

Comment: Hi. He logged in with his cell which is a Samsung fone and he has Microsoft one drive

Comment: Well it seems that confirms my thought & answer. Please up vote (up arrow) my answer if you believe it helped. Accept my answer if you believe it answered your initial questions which I believe it did.

Comment: It did help thank you. Not sure what up arrow means. First time on this platform 

Comment: To the left of this answer is up arrow, a number, down arrow, & a check mark. Checkmark means you accept my answer, up means it helps, down means you didn't like it: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @gregg, I am sure that I have read in one of the metas that begging for votes is not cricket.  And its not as if you are short of reps.